# How can I request Facebook publish_actions permission wfrom my Swift app?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my application I'm sending photo to my backend code. I also want to publish this photo to user's facebook wall. User is logged in into my app with FB account already, but I did not yet request his `publish_actions` permission.

In my application user has a `UISwitch` that - when turned on - should check if user granted the `publish_actions` permission, and if he didn't yet - request it from the user.

This is my code so far:

```
if !(FBSDKAccessToken.current().hasGranted("publish_actions")) {

    print("Request publish_actions permissions")
    let login: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()

    login.logIn(withPublishPermissions: ["publish_actions"], from: self) { (result, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error!)
        } else if (result?.isCancelled)! {
            print("Canceled")
        } else if (result?.grantedPermissions.contains("publish_actions"))! {
            print("permissions granted")

        }
    }
}else {

}
```

The problem is that when user taps the UISwitch, it opens Safari immediately to ask him about login to Facebook. When he does log in again, there's a message "You have already authorized <>". When user clicks `OK`, he goes back to the app and in the console I see `Canceled`.

This doesn't seem right to me, so my question is - what's the best way of asking user to allow for this permission?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: Any solution? Share for others

Answer (score 0):

Some facebook features need you to send your app for review by facebook before they can be used. You are trying to gain "publish_actions" permission with your own facebook account before you have sent your facebook app for review. In development mode create a test account from developers.facebook.com to test these features.